# Is a Riccati BSDE explicitly solvable?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, martingales, stochastic-integrals, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Let $W=\{W_t\}_{t\in[0;T]}$ be a real-valued Brownian motion, $\{F_t\}_{t\in [0;T]}$ the filtration generated by $W$, augmented with the nullsets, let $C\in (0;\infty)$ and $\{a_t\}_{t\in[0;T]}$ be a bounded and adapted process. Let $A_t := \int^t_0 a_s \mathrm ds$.

**Question**: Is the BSDE
$$
\mathrm dX_t = C X_t \big( a_t + X_t \big) \mathrm dt + Z_t \mathrm dW_t,
\quad
\lim_{t\to T} X_t = \infty
$$
explicitly solvable? (I only require that $Z \in L^2(\Omega\times[0;t])$ for every $t < T$.)

If $a$ was deterministic, then
$$
X_t := \frac {\exp(C A_t)} {C \int^T_t \exp(C A_s) \mathrm ds}
$$
would be a solution.

**What I've tried**: As in the case of linear BSDEs, I set $X_t = B_t M_t$ where $\mathrm dB_t = b_t \mathrm dt$ and $\mathrm dM_t = m_t \mathrm dW_t$. Then
$$
M_t b_t \mathrm dt + B_t m_t \mathrm dW_t
=
M_t \mathrm dB_t + B_t \mathrm dM_t
=
\mathrm dX_t
=
C X_t \big( a_t + X_t \big) \mathrm dt + Z_t \mathrm dW_t
=
C B_t M_t \big( a_t + B_t M_t \big) \mathrm dt + Z_t \mathrm dW_t
$$
Dividing both absolutely continuous parts by $M_t$ leads to the ODE
$$
\mathrm dB_t
=
C B_t \big( a_t + B_t M_t \big) \mathrm dt
$$
This leads to the general solution
$$
B_t
=
\frac {\exp(C A_t)} {K - C \int^t_0 M_s \exp(A_s) \mathrm ds}
$$
Now it seems that I would have a solution if I found a process $M$ being a martingale on every $[0;t]$ with $t < T$ such that
$$
C \int^T_0 M_s \exp(A_s) \mathrm ds
=
K.
$$
Since we can multiply $B$ by a constant and and divide $M$ by the same constant, we can just set $K=C$, this leads to the condition
$$
\int^T_0 M_s \exp(A_s) \mathrm ds
=
1.
$$

Comment: Cross-posted: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/421001/is-a-riccati-bsde-explicitly-solvable

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that. The question is probably somewhere in the overlap of research level and graduate basics.